# When did Starfleet use stasis pods?

Tags: star-trek, starfleet-command

From Star Trek Voyager: [The Thaw](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/219.htm)

> JANEWAY: Could it be generating an artificial environment of some
> sort?
>
> KES: Artificial environment?
>
> JANEWAY: Years ago, **Starfleet used
> a technology to assist deep space travel that kept the body in stasis**,
> but provided a mental landscape to keep the mind active and alert.

Has it been shown in canon when Starfleet used stasis pods?

I would assume after the development of the warp drive, but before Archer's time.

Comment: Your logic is a little flawed.  Janeway says "years ago".  That sounds more like five or ten years than like over 200 years.  Wouldn't Janeway have said "centuries"  if it was over 200 years?  And the Federation Starfleet began when or after the Federation was formed, after the events in Enterprise.  Yes, there was an Earth Starfleet in Enterprise, but I don't anyone ever mentioned how long it had been operating so it might have been started only a few years before Enterprise.  And I don't know if Janeway would have considered the Earth Starfleet to be "Starfleet", her Federation Starfleet.

Comment: @M.A.Golding - I thought about that before posting, but if we take Janeway's comment as is, when would they have used it? They have ships that can go at least Warp 9. I would assume before or Archers time, if they wanted to push the boundaries of space travel. Another flaw I realized is if SF could create virtual worlds, won't they have been used in Enterprise? Perhaps even a mention?

Comment: Wasn't Khan in a stasis pod when he was retrieved by the Enterprise in TOS: Space Seed?

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I forgot about that, but was that StarFleet stasis pods? I'm looking for any situation in the context of Janeway's comment.

Comment: Originally I thought you meant medical stasis which was a TNG thing.  The patient usually died immediately in TOS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We hear of at least one example of stasis pods being used in the Starfleet era, from Harry Kim. Admittedly, this may be a '*[tall tale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tall_tale)*' but the mention of them doesn't elicit surprise among the listeners, not least from Seven who has an encyclopaedic knowledge of Starfleet history and tech.

> **KIM:** *It was around **2210**. My uncle Jack was on a deep space mission to Beta Capricus.*
> **PARIS:** *That's when deep space meant the next star over.*
> **KIM:** ***And that was when they still had to go into stasis.** So, Jack put his crew under as soon as they left orbit, and piloted the ship by himself for six months.*
> **NEELIX:** *No contact with anybody along the way?*
> **KIM:** *There wasn't anybody along the way. Not back then. The transmitter wasn't even subspace. It took weeks to get a message back to Earth.*
> **SEVEN:** *I would prefer stasis.*
> **PARIS:** *Me too. That long alone, I'd probably go a little batty.*
> **KIM:** *So, six months to Beta Capricus and when they finally arrive, there's nothing there.*
> **NEELIX:** *No planets?*
> **KIM:** *No. No star, no nothing. It turns out Beta Capricus was just an EM echo of a distant galaxy.*
> **SEVEN:** *What was his course of action?*
> **KIM:** *What else could he do? He turned the ship around and headed home.*
> **JANEWAY:** *And the crew?*
> **KIM:** *He figured there was no reason to bother them. There's nothing to see, nothing to do. So **six months later he gets back to Earth, brings everybody out of stasis, and they wake up wondering why they haven't left orbit.***
>
> <sub><sup>[VOY: 11:59](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/11:59_(episode))</sup></sub>

Comment: "EM echo of a distant galaxy", the technobabble is so dumb it almost wraps around to poetry.

Comment: @Harabeck - The correct term is *Trek*nobabble. And yes, the fail in this sentence is mighty, hence why I thought it might be a shaggy dog story by Kim.

Comment: It's not a real star but close enough to a real name for a tall tale... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_Capricorni

Comment: @lucasbachmann - Since there's nothing actually there, I assume that the name was deprecated